# Write to database when Laravel user attemps to logs in, logs in successfully, and logs out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm seeking a way to write to a database log when a user attempts to log in, logs in successfully, and logs out. Laravel version: 5.4.25. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be more specific about the problem you are facing. What have you tried, where have you failed? Include a bit of reference code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [authentication events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events) for this.

Just add a listener to the events you want to be logged and write to your log when they fire.

Comment: How do you write to log? Is there another file where db write code can be inserted?

Comment: Well if you want to log to your database you are going to need to make a migration for a logs table, create a corresponding model and then create the records for each event.